# Please help me with this question..... I look at it for 1 hour and still have no idea where to start

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

Consider a thin rectangular metal plate, as shown in Figure 1 (the shaded region), whose faces are perfectly insulated so that it is eﬀectively a two-dimensional plate.

[image: t]

- (a) Suppose that the upper side of the plate along y = b = 2 is held at a constant temperature of 75◦C, the two sides along x = 0 and x = a = 1 are perfectly insulated and the lower side along y = 0 is held at 0◦C. By the method of separation of variables, derive the steady-state temperature u(x, y) of the metal plate. Is the solution as you would’ve expected? Why?
- (b) Suppose now that the upper side along y = b = 2 is held at a temperature of 80x(1 − x)◦C, the two sides along x = 0 and x = a = 1 are held at 0◦C and the lower side along y = 0 is perfectly insulated. By the method of separation of variables, derive the steady-state temperature u(x, y) of the metal plate. State explicitly the ﬁrst three non-zero terms of the solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by the heat equation, where you assume there is no time dependence and the thermal conductivity, $k$, is a material constant. The equation is the following
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} =0
\end{equation}
with the following boundary conditions
\begin{align}
u(x,b)&=75\\
u(x,0)&=0
\end{align}

And as suggested by the problem, you should use separation of variables, meaning $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ to find the solution.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post answers to homework questions. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Pinkman98 thank you for telling me where to start.

Comment: @JohnRennie I am struggling here and you're asking people not to help me. What are you doing? At least he is teaching me where to start.

Comment: @hames This is not a site for homework help. If that's what you're here for, you might want to check [this list of other sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391) that are more focused in that direction.

Comment: @JohnRennie I need people to explain with the solution too. I don't want the answer. I need help. Can you understand me ?